# Fetch the response body on failure using file_get_contents

Tags: php, ajax, file-get-contents

The documentation of file_get_contents says

```
 On failure, file_get_contents() will return FALSE.
```

I am integrating with a system which returns error messages in the response and sets the status code to "50x"

Is there a way, I can still fetch the response content ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$curl = curl_init('http://example.net');
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

however this may not satisfy your needs, as it requires curl

you may also ignore errors, to still use `file_get_contents`

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'ignore_errors' => true
     )
));
```

Comment: Thanks, chose CURL itself. Although, if I mention 'ignore_errors' it returns the body of the response instead of false ?

Comment: yep, just returns body